# A* algorithm for cars displayed in a parking

Tags: algorithm, a-star, heuristics

I have to implement a states problem solution using the A* algorithm, and I am having a hard time trying to understand its procedure. Here I explain in what consists the problem and what my doubts are:

There's a parking display like this, where each car is described with a number and a letter:

```
A1 A3 B2 __ C1
B1 A2 __ __ C2
__ B3 A4 __ __
```

And I have to use the A* algorithm to find the path for changing the cars' positions, let's say, to this:

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 __
__ B1 B2 B3 __
__ __ __ C1 C2
```

The allowed movements are:

```
Going to the right: cost = 1
Going to the left: cost = 2
Changing lines (or entering the same) and stay in the left end: cost = 3
Changing lines (or entering the same) and stay in the right end: cost = 4
```

This is all the information we get about the issue, and here are my doubts:

1. How to implement the states: object with cars and positions, matrix with cars...
2. How to implement the operators: I suppose there'd be 4, the same as the allowed movements, but my concern is related with how applying them (next doubt)
3. How to expand the following nodes in the A* algorithm: should I be moving each car until it is in its final state, or should I treat them as a whole?? It is pretty confusing :S
4. I've been thinking about the Heuristic Function to use here, and the one I could come up with was the Manhattan Distance, but I am not sure if it is correct since I don't really know how to expand the nodes and find the next states.

I really hope someone can help me and bring me some light in all of this. Thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: Hint to get you started: a node represents the whole configuration of cars and you come from one node to the next by doing one of the allowed movements.

Comment: thank you @Henry :)

Comment: so did this solve your issue? @MartaLobo

Comment: @yacc nope, I still have the mayor problem of how to use the operators and how to display the different states, as I don't know if I have to do it car by car, trying to get them to their final position, or with all the cars at the same time...